# Make a file writeStream Observable on Angular

Tags: angular, observable, fs

I'm struggling trying to guess how can I create a method, that can be subscribed, returning the location of a file, just when it has been downloaded. The method now is wrong :     `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.`

```
downloadFile(url, location):  Observable<any>{
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(location);
  https.get(url, function (response) {
     response.pipe(file);
     file.on('finish', function (d) {
           file.close();
        return Observable.of(location);
  });
});
```

Any idea ? Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi mate, yes u r not returning to the correct context. This wont work. I suggest using a separate Subject to which every component can subscribe in order to get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this working solution :

```
import { NextObserver } from 'rxjs/Observer';

downloadFile(url):  Observable<any>{

return Observable.create((observer: NextObserver <any>) => {
   const file = fs.createWriteStream(location);
  https.get(url, function (response) {
    response.pipe(file);
   });

 file.on('finish', () => {
      file.close();
        observer.next(location);
        observer.complete();
    });
});
}
```

Comment: how to use `fs` in angular?